# How do I set a password request to connect USB devices?

Tags: security, usb, devices, administration

I need to make it so that when I connect any device to USB, be it a drive, smartphone, printer, etc. The system will ask for a password to authorise this connection, and the device will only connect and start working after entering the correct password. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that is currently not possible with how USB works. (And partially, because of how USB works under Linux.)

- when you plug in a USB device, it gets detected by the hardware (otherwise nothing could tell your computer there's new USB hardware, and also, that's necessary to keep the bus running)
- the operating system has a data structure internally in which it stores which USB devices there are. It has to make a new entry there, something like "there's a new unknown type of device at bus address 03:01"
- to figure out what kind of device that is, it has to ask the device: hey, tell me, who are you?
- the device answers with a vendor ID and product ID. These are just two numbers, which it is free to invent. "Benign" USB devices of course choose to send the IDs that properly represent them. Absolutely no mechanism exists in USB to somehow verify that's true.
- the device also sends a string containing a description of what it is. Same deal: device can freely pick that, is not forced to send the same thing every time.

So, here is the first thing we need to realize: if you want to protect against malicious devices, that's going to be a problem. I can -trivially- take a 5€ microcontroller development board and program it to say "hey, I'm a keyboard and exactly the same type of keyboard my programmer saw on the receptionist's desk when he walked into the the office of the company", and your Linux will have to trust that. Why? It has no way of telling truth from lies, and you have to whitelist the company keyboards, otherwise you can't log in.

But if you whitelist the keyboards, then you would instantly accept my device without confirmation. My pseudokeyboard would then proceed to, within less than a second, upload all the user's files to a central server, or delete everything that the user can delete, or install a keylogger¹.

It, by the way, gets worse: if you plug in a USB device, and the kernel identifies it as a device for which it already has loaded a driver (e.g. for another pen drive), the driver might attach to that device without ever telling user land. And if nobody in user land can notice, you cannot be shown a confirmation dialog.

But if you want to protect against malicious users, this scheme is useless anyways. Either they don't care if you know that they entered a password to allow too connect a USB device they really shouldn't, or, they pull the same trick as described with a pseudokeyboard, a legitimate printer and an in-cable USB hub and a colleague. Colleague turns on printer, enters password for a device that claims it's a brother printer but in reality is something malicious, wonders why they have to enter the password twice(second time for the real printer) and don't realize they have been had.

---

¹ Keyboards are nice, because practically any personal computer has some device that acts as a keyboard – even if that's just the volume buttons on the headset – and if I'm a keyboard, I can just emulate-press the buttons I need to get a terminal (<kbd>win</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd><kbd>Alt+F2</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd><kbd>Alt+F2</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>… until I'm positively sure at least one terminal window must have opened), then do whatever sinister stuff I want to do (<kbd>e</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>⏘</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>…), then close all windows that I might have opened making sure at least one terminal window was open (<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd><kbd>Alt+F4</kbd><kbd>Alt+F4</kbd><kbd>Alt+F4</kbd><kbd>Alt+F4</kbd>…)

Answer (score 2):

Even though it may not normally be visible to the user, all USB device additions, changes and removals trigger udev events.

And the Linux USB support already includes a feature that can be set to disallow the use of USB devices until they have somehow been vetted by the user-space first. See: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/authorization.txt

By default, all USB devices will be authorized for use. The first step would be to change that default:

```
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*
do
    echo 0 > "$i/authorized_default"
done
```

Then you could add an udev rule to use D-Bus or similar to pass information about any new or changed USB device to a user-space tool that would handle identifying the device in a human-readable way and asking the password. Since modern versions of udev disallow long-running processes and may apply various levels of sandboxing to prevent direct interaction with the user session, such an intermediate step will be necessary.

Once the password is successfully entered, the element that checks the password would add it to some sort of whitelist of accepted devices, and flip the "authorized" attribute in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/<some path..>` to 1 (true). Before that is done, even if the drivers for that particular type of device are already loaded, they won't even get information that a device exists.

Authorizing a device would probably trigger other udev events, so you might need another udev rule before the one mentioned above, that would first check if the device is already whitelisted and if so, would non-interactively allow it.

That check would have to include checking the device type too: if a device that previously was whitelisted as a USB storage device suddenly reconnects and now claims to be a USB hub with a USB storage device, keyboard and mouse attached, it should trigger a new password request and highlight the fact that the device reports functionality that is different from before.

You would have to be extra strict with anything that claims to be a keyboard-like device - but you would also have to have some way to deal with things like "the boss soaked both his keyboard and mouse in coffee and needs his computer usable again ASAP". So if keyboards are checked by individual serial numbers, then the support person needs an "universally accepted master keyboard" so that they will be able to authorize a new mouse and keyboard to any system that has lost all their previously-authorized ones.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know if udev's authorize. But the malicious user must not know that "master key" serial number, just as a small complication